# Is there a way to trace more details of unacked push notification

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a **Pub/Sub push subscription** that sends notifications to our endpoint.
Recently, it started to receive the **302** status for some of the requests - **response_code=redirect_found_error_302**.
We've verified, this 302 response is not returned by the App server, but probably by the Firewall.
Our Firewall support cannot identify the problem and asks to provide more details about failing requests.
Is there any option to log a specific push request failure details in push subscription? For example to get the body or the location header of the 302 response?

Comment: If you contact Google Cloud support, they should be able to give you more fine-grained logs.

Comment: An alternative, DIY approach is to drain the subscription and redirect the subscription to a push endpoint without a firewall. Stop publishing data to the topic and ack all of the messages. Update the subscription to point to a different endpoint. CPS will retry the failing pushes to the new endpoint. You can set up logging at the new endpoint.

Comment: Or you can log on the publishing side which messages are being sent and their message ids, and log which messages are being acked on the subscribing side, and then do the set difference to see the missing messages.

Comment: The error code mentioned is not listed in the [PubSub Error Codes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes), as @Prad Nelluru commented reach out the GCP support team could be a good option to investigate further, also,  I was wondering if this 302 error code is also retrieved in the browser ? If yes  maybe  you can check the  browser activity to determine where this issue comes from

Comment: There are more push error codes than the error codes listed on that page. The errors on that page are standard codes used by Google applications. The push errors D.Smeliansky is seeing are from the target of the push subscription. Whichever HTTP code it returns are shown in the metric.